# how to work with java making button? in Android app

Tags: java, android

how to work with this type button.
if someone pressed the button it will put the string value for next activity and the value will be button name.

```
LinearLayout loj = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for (int i = 0; i < eachname.length; i++) {
    Button tv = new Button(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText(eachname[i]);
    tv.setId(i);
    loj.addView(tv);

} '
```

Comment: Do You think aboyt listeners? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: But what will be id in this code?

Comment: Please stop reposting this. **Intent** is how you pass data. Buttons don't have names. The string value is clearly `eachname[i]`

Comment: Note: If you delete and make a new account, you could get banned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
LinearLayout loj = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for (int i = 0; i < eachname.length; i++) {
    Button tv = new Button(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText(eachname[i]);
    tv.setId(i);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_STRING_VALUE",tv.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    loj.addView(tv);

}
```